# Having problems with curves 2.93.1

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm having a problem with the modifier curve, I would like to know what I'm doing wrong, the curves is flattening and widening an object, like this:

[image]

In case I'm being a noob, sorry in advance.

Comment: please provide your blend file because you gave us nearly no information...might be because you didn't apply scale, but depends how you got this effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is normal. The spokes are being stretched along that axis because it is the outside of a turn. If it were the inside, they would’ve been squeezed thinner.

To make them stay the same size, I recommend using a particle system instead.